# Count Max Values of Top 1,2,3 on another workbook

Tags: excel, formula, maxifs

I've trying to come up with a formula to automatically populate top 1,2,3 text occurrences from another Workbook, however I have multiple criterias that seem to be making it more difficult for me.

So in Workbook 1, I have:

```
Column A
Dates ranging from 2106-Present

Column B
Random PartNumbers with a mix or numbers and letters
(Note partnumbers are not a definite list as they change and new one implemented)

Column C 
Location
```

This list has over 10k records

I'm creating a separate workbook (template)

```
Column/Row A1 Top part Number 1 
Column/Row A2 Top part Number 2
Column/Row A3 Top part Number 3
```

Formula has to have a condition for month range and location

```
Column B1 would display the part number (1st place)
Column C2 would display the count
And so on...
```

For example:

Template would display:

```
Top Part Number | Part Number | Count
            1   |      P23    |    23
            2   |      345    |   19
            3   |      D43    |    16
```

(Count is determined by month and location of choice)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This has been answered Many times. what have you tried? what gets you close and were are you lacking?

Comment: I need help writing the formula

Comment: All examples I have seen have a reference column to match the max of the given cell. I don't know what part numbers to reference and I don't know how to write a formula that will give me top 1, top 2, top 3

Comment: Can someone help me with this formula? I have not found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.